# Enter key dosen't work after coding it with java

Tags: java, swing, key, enter

i get a trouble when i write this code for a jButton to open new jfame and all that is by using the "Enter key" but it didn't work ,this the code i have writen :

```
 if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         Chooser ch = new Chooser();
           ch.setVisible(true);

    }
```

So! why? Please help me and thanks.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556).  BTW - Add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton` and it will typically respond to the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons don't need a `KeyListener` (and for the most part shouldn't use them), they use an `ActionListener` to respond to all activation events, including the action key (which isn't always the <kbd>Enter</kbd>), mouse clicks, keyboard shortcuts and programmatically triggered events, it's a much more simplified API.

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

You can also set a button as the "default" button which can be activated when not focused (so long as the currently focused component doesn't use/consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key)

See [`JRootPane#setDefaultButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton(javax.swing.JButton)) and [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Comment: off topic but how did you get that Enter key so nicely?

Comment: <kbd>...</kbd> ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did You remember to add Listener for jButton ?
Please give more code in Your example/
Moreover... searching in google could give interesting results:
[KeyListener in Textfield not firing when press enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309510/keylistener-in-textfield-not-firing-when-press-enter)

Comment: With all due respect, the linked answers are erroneous and misleading. the button API uses the `ActionListener` API to provide event notification which takes into consideration the "action" key (which isn't always the [Enter] key), mouse presses, keyboard shortcuts and programmatically triggered events